# Dynamically create DOM in ReactJS from json string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following JSON string from which I need to dynamically create DOM of the form:

```
    {
        "formData": [{
            "inputType": "text",
            "type": "string",
            "min": 10,
            "label": "Enter Name:",
            "objectId": "test1"
        }],
        "gridLayout": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "column": [
                        {
                            "width": "4",
                            "id": "test1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

from the `gridLayout` object, I wish to create bootstrap style grid. For instance, first `row`object of the JSON's `"rows"` has 1 column in the `columns` object with width of 4. Thus, the layout for that row should be

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="test1">

    </div>
</div>
```

Later, using `formData` object of JSON, `TextBox` component should be appended to grid layout like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="test1">
        <TextBox />
    </div>
</div>
```

For now, I have written code to display the `TextBox` component as it is without the grid layout in following way.

*Form.jsx:*

```
class Form extends React.Component {
getComponent = (formObj, index) => {
    let returnString;
    if (formObj.inputType === 'text') {
        returnString = (<TextBox key={index} />);
    }

    return returnString;
}


render() {
    let formData = JSON.parse(this.getData()).formData;
    return (
        <React.Fragment> {formData.map((o, index) => this.getComponent(o, index))} </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}
```

Thus now, how do I dynamically create the Grid Layout and insert the TextBox component in it?

Comment: On what basis does the `TextBox` end up in a particular column? You have duplicate `id`s, so it's difficult to find the correct column.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb: Sorry about that, I have updated the JSON to contain only one row object. Actually, in the original case there were two `TextBox` components for two `row` objects. This one's shorter version of the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be achieved by using a combination of array methods. Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to render your `gridLayout` `div`s as necessary. Use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the props of the correct `TextBox` from `formData`.

I've simplified `formData`, but added more rows and columns to give you a complete picture.

```js
const data = {
  "formData": [{
    "label": "Enter Name:",
    "objectId": "test1"
  }, {
    "label": "Enter Address:",
    "objectId": "test2"
  }, {
    "label": "Enter Number:",
    "objectId": "test3"
  }, {
    "label": "Enter Something:",
    "objectId": "test4"
  }],
  "gridLayout": {
    "rows": [{
        "column": [{
          "width": "4",
          "id": "test1"
        }, {
          "width": "4",
          "id": "test2"
        }]
      },
      {
        "column": [{
          "width": "6",
          "id": "test3"
        }, {
          "width": "6",
          "id": "test4"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}

const TextBox = ({ label }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <label>{label}</label>
  </React.Fragment>
);

const Form = ({ data: { formData, gridLayout } }) => {
  return gridLayout.rows.map(row => {
    return (
      <div class="row">
        {row.column.map(col => {
          const textBoxProps = formData.find(data => data.objectId === col.id);
          // REPLACE col- with col-md-. Done here to demonstrate layout in small snippet output area
          return (
            <div className={`col-${col.width} borderedCol`}>
              <TextBox {...textBoxProps} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  });
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form data={data} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
/* ONLY for demo purposes */
.borderedCol {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sure that works! Thanks. But can I separate grid creation code from component insertion code? Something like, in the grid creation I will leave the placeholders as `id` and in component insertion, I will insert the component as per the id.

Comment: You can separate it if you like. But there needs to be a function call which will return what you need to render there.

Comment: That's quite obvious. But my question is how do you do that in Reactjs? How do you create plain HTML with place holders and later refer those placeholders to add children in them?

Comment: You can replace `<TextBox />` with say `{getTextBox()}`. I don't understand your second question as such. What do you mean by _later_? You have to return a tree of JSX elements from the render call and React just creates/manages the HTML for you. If this is not answering your question, then please edit the question to explain what problem you're facing or ask a new question.

Comment: Also, you could read about [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). That's what you return from a render call in React.

Comment: By _later_ i meant, after creating grid, next step would be to insert components into the placeholders. Anyway, I can live with this code though. Thanks!